Compressing and removing files in Powershell
I have written below Powershell code to compress and then delete files. I have ~3,00,000 files in source folder with different modified date. This script takes more than 18 hours to compress file for a particular Year-Month grouping. Example - I have ~40,000 files for 2024-07 and it takes more than 18 hours to complete. Can someone please advise how can this be optimized.
cls

$server = ($ServerName.Split(',')[0]) -replace 'QL', ''

$sourcePath = '\\'+$server+'\c$\Temp\Notifications'
$destinationPath = '\\'+$server+'\c$\Temp\NotificationsArchive'

$currentYearMonth = Get-Date -Format "yyyy-MM"
$previousYearMonth = (Get-Date).AddMonths(-1).ToString("yyyy-MM")

# Get all files from the shared path that match the date modified filter, excluding directories
$files = Get-ChildItem -Path $sourcePath -Recurse | Where-Object { $_.LastWriteTime.ToString("yyyy-MM") -ne $currentYearMonth -and $_.LastWriteTime.ToString("yyyy-MM") -ne $previousYearMonth }

# Group the files by Year-Month of their LastWriteTime
$groupedFiles = $files | Group-Object { "{0:yyyy-MM}" -f $_.LastWriteTime }

# Process each group to create a zip file
foreach ($group in $groupedFiles) {
    # Extract the group key (yyyy-MM) to use in the zip file name
    $zipFileName = "$($group.Name).zip"
    $zipFilePath = Join-Path -Path $destinationPath -ChildPath $zipFileName

    # Use Compress-Archive to create the zip file for each group of files
    # Adding -Force to overwrite if the zip file already exists
    Compress-Archive -Path ($group.Group.FullName) -DestinationPath $zipFilePath -Force

    Write-Output "Created zip file: $zipFilePath with $($group.Count) files."

    # Remove the files after they are compressed
    foreach ($file in $group.Group) {
        try {
            Remove-Item -Path $file.FullName -Recurse -Force
            Write-Output "Deleted file: $($file.FullName)"
        } catch {
            Write-Error "Failed to delete file: $($file.FullName). Error: $_"
        }
    }
}

Write-Output "Compression complete!"


Looks like your files are located on a network file share - opening, reading, closing and deleting lots of small files over the network is probably the biggest bottleneck. If it’s a server-based share (e.g. a windows or Linux vm) you could try running the script interactively on that so the files are on the local disk, which will eliminate network latency.

Alternatively, copy all the files locally, run your script on them, then copy the results back up to the network. The script will run a lot faster then, although it’ll probably take the same total time if you include the file copying steps…

another thing that might help is using 7zip instead of Compress-Archive, if that's possible.

You could try to create an array of path
$filePaths = $group.Group | ForEach-Object { $_.FullName }

Then pass it to Compress-Archive instead of $group.Group.FullName
Compress-Archive -Path $filePaths -DestinationPath $zipFilePath -Force

You can also use Parallel module if possible
ForEach-Object -Parallel

Final script will be somenthing like this (should you test it):
cls

$server = ($ServerName.Split(',')[0]) -replace 'QL', ''
$sourcePath = '\\'+$server+'\c$\Temp\Notifications'
$destinationPath = '\\'+$server+'\c$\Temp\NotificationsArchive'

$currentYearMonth = Get-Date -Format "yyyy-MM"
$previousYearMonth = (Get-Date).AddMonths(-1).ToString("yyyy-MM")

# Get all files from the shared path that match the date modified filter, excluding directories
$files = Get-ChildItem -Path $sourcePath -Recurse -File | Where-Object { 
    $fileDate = $_.LastWriteTime.ToString("yyyy-MM")
    $fileDate -ne $currentYearMonth -and $fileDate -ne $previousYearMonth 
}

# Group the files by Year-Month of their LastWriteTime
$groupedFiles = $files | Group-Object { "{0:yyyy-MM}" -f $_.LastWriteTime }

# Process each group to create a zip file in parallel mode
$groupedFiles | ForEach-Object -Parallel {
    param ($group, $destinationPath)

    $zipFileName = "$($group.Name).zip"
    $zipFilePath = Join-Path -Path $destinationPath -ChildPath $zipFileName

    # Create an array of file paths
    $filePaths = $group.Group | ForEach-Object { $_.FullName }

    # Use Compress-Archive to create the zip file for each group of files
    Compress-Archive -Path $filePaths -DestinationPath $zipFilePath -Force

    Write-Output "Created zip file: $zipFilePath with $($group.Count) files."

    # Remove the files after they are compressed
    $filePaths | ForEach-Object {
        try {
            Remove-Item -Path $_ -Force
            Write-Output "Deleted file: $_"
        } catch {
            Write-Error "Failed to delete file: $_. Error: $_"
        }
    }
} -ArgumentList $_, $destinationPath -ThrottleLimit 4

Write-Output "Compression complete!"

IF not necessary have a full log, I prefer log ONLY ERROR to improve performance.

Thanks Nifriz but this still takes a lot of time, I have started this script and it has only compressed 10% of files and already taken more than 3 hours
